# Curl commands not executed properly when escuted through shell script

Tags: json, content-type

I have a curl which sends application/json data .when i type this url directly through unix console,it works fine.But when i take this url and store it in a csv file and through shell script try accessing this file and read each curl and esecute it through backticks i am facing two problems

- 1) it is not allowing spaces in the json data being posted
- 2) the content type is not being set

Please find below the same url

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'content-type:application/json' -H "Accept:application/json" -d '{"startTime":1426172400000,"endTime":1426173300000,"attributes":{"title":"X X X","link":"https://someurl.com}}' http://10.10.7.90:9084/myapp/rest/app/706128.api`
```

Comment: try adding `echo` to the start and see if it is actually executing what you think it is executing

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue .It was in my shell script .Insead of using the back tick '`' to execute the curl ,i used eval curl .which solved the issue